# Whenever I run this code It crashes in the android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, crash

I consistantly get an error when I run this line

```
moreContent.addView(findViewById(moreViews[0]), 0);
extra code:
private int[] moreViews={
    0x7f060006, 0x7f060007, 0x7f060009, 0x7f06000a, 0x7f06000b
};
```

Comment: and a last tip in addition to the answers: Use the LogCat view of eclipse or run `adb logcat` in a console to get all errors and messages your emulator (or device) might print...

Comment: Post your R.java class and more details so we can effectively assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not reference the ids by the hex number, but using `R.id.xxx`.

Without the logcat is impossible to tell, but most probably there is no resource found.

Comment: I checked the logcat It was okay, and I changed the format of my references it still doesn't work addView(anything) causes a crash

Answer (score 1):

Use R.layout. rather than its actual id.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the raw resource values. They will change when AAPT generates new ones. Use the constants defined in R.java. This is terrible programming practice. Make use of the constants!

```
private int[] moreView = {R.id.myView1, R.id.myView2, ...};
```

Comment: I did that and I still get the same result